What is the simplest way to read a string until the first space character?
I have a string which contains some command line arguments for a calculator. What sort of argument it is can be determined by the first word in the string. For example:
"delete_var x" 

Would be a command to delete the variable x. This is why I want to separate the first word of the string. The user-input is collected using std::getline() and I can not change this.
One way to do this is to just make a loop which reads each character until a space character is found. But I was wondering if there was a simpler way using the >> operator. So the code would look something like this:
std::string full_command = "delete_var x"
std::string first_argument;
full_command >> first_argument; // "delete_var"

All I could find was using the fstream header to do this with files:
string s; 
ifstream file("example.txt"); 
file >> s;

But what about single strings?

One way to do this is to just make a loop which reads each character until a space character is found. -- There is no need to write the loop this way.  Using std::istringstream, the stream object automatically will space delimit the input in a simple while loop using operator >>.

Put the string into a std::istringstream and then use operator>> to read space-separated words from that stream

If you want to do it with std::string then https://onlinegdb.com/-bQ6x4FD3
If you want to do it with char* then https://onlinegdb.com/apiKPZV0U
